# Compile latex in c#

Tags: pdftex

im making a .bat file to compile a .tex file to pdf, when i run it directly the .bat file it works fine, but when i run it in c# the error "pdflatex: invalid argument" appers

```
static void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        Process p1 = new Process();
        p1.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\users\miguelangel\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PruebaLatex\PruebaLatex\batch.bat";
        p1.StartInfo.Arguments =@"c:\users\miguelangel\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PruebaLatex\PruebaLatex\prueba.tex"; 
        p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        try
        {
            p1.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(e); 
        }           
    }
```

Please help me :(, i dont know what else to do, this is the .bat file

```
pdflatex prueba.tex
```

pause

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you post this on http://superuser.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. It's really a c# question, not a TeX question.

Comment: It could be due to improper escaping of the space in the directory names. Try to move everything to a directory without a space in the complete path.